Problem getting Mojolicious routes to work
The following route definition works nicely
sub load_routes {
 my($self) = @_;

 my $root = $self->routes;

 $root->get('/')->to(                 controller=>'Snipgen', action=>'indexPage');
 $root->any('/Snipgen')          ->to(controller=>'Snipgen', action=>'SnipgenPage1');
 $root->any('/Snipgen/show')     ->to(controller=>'Snipgen', action=>'SnipgenPage2');
 }

and "./script/snipgen.pl routes -v" gives
/              ....  GET               ^
/Snipgen       ....  *    Snipgen      ^\/Snipgen
/Snipgen/show  ....  *    Snipgenshow  ^\/Snipgen\/show


but this fails for 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/Snipgen/' giving page not found
sub load_routes {
 my($self) = @_;

 my $root = $self->routes;

 $root->get('/')->to(controller=>'Snipgen', action=>'indexPage');
 my $myaction = $root->any('/Snipgen')->to(controller=>'Snipgen', action=>'SnipgenPage1');
 $myaction->any('/show')              ->to(controller=>'Snipgen', action=>'SnipgenPage2');
 }

and the corresponding "./script/snipgen.pl routes -v" gives
/         ....  GET           ^
/Snipgen  ....  *    Snipgen  ^\/Snipgen
  +/show  ....  *    show     ^\/show


The SnipgenPageXX subs all have 'return;' as their last line. Any idea what is going wrong?

Mojolicious documentation states, that A route with children can't match on its own . You can work around this by adding a child route with '/'. Another option is to use under() which offers more control by adding a dispatch target for the partial route.
As suggested in the comments by brian d foy, you can display the routes of your app by passing a routes option to your application script like so:
perl -Ilib script/my_app routes -v.
See the documentation here and here.
The Mojolicious page not found template also displays your routes at the top of the page.
You want the routes to look like this:
/         ....  *           ^
/Snipgen  ....  *  Snipgen  ^\/Snipgen
  +/      ....  *           ^
  +/show  ....  *  show     ^\/show

Instead of:
/         ....  *           ^
/Snipgen  ....  *  Snipgen  ^\/Snipgen
  +/show  ....  *  show     ^\/show

Adding a child with '/':
sub load_routes {
    my($self) = @_;

    my $root = $self->routes;

    $root->any('/')->to(controller=>'Snipgen', action=>'indexPage');
    my $myaction = $root->any('/Snipgen')->to(controller => 'Snipgen');;
    $myaction->any('/')->to( action=>'SnipgenPage1');
    $myaction->any('/show')->to( action=>'SnipgenPage2');
}

Using under()
sub load_routes {
    my($self) = @_;

    my $root = $self->routes;

    $root->get('/')->to(controller=>'Snipgen', action=>'indexPage');
    my $myaction = $root->under('/Snipgen');#->to('Auth#check')
    $myaction->any('/')->to(controller=>'Snipgen', action=>'SnipgenPage1');
    $myaction->any('/show')->to(controller=>'Snipgen', action=>'SnipgenPage2');
}

Or add a child route like so:
sub load_routes {
    my($self) = @_;
    my $root = $self->routes;
    
    $root->get('/')->to(controller=>'Snipgen', action=>'indexPage');
    my $myaction = $root->get('Snipgen')
        ->to(controller=>'Snipgen', action=>'SnipgenPage1')
           ->add_child(Mojolicious::Routes::Route->new);
    $myaction->get('show')->to(controller=>'Snipgen', action=>'SnipgenPage2');
}


If you run perl -Ilib script/myapp.pl routes -v, you can see how mojo is deciding to route things. You should see that there is no route which matched the URL.

I never quite understood what "routes -v" is displaying. Using it here is a good example, the output differs for the two cases, but as best I can tell it still says both urls are matched. How does it show no route matched the URL?

@ferg You can tell by the indentation and + sign, that Snipgen is an intermediate  route and will not match on its own.

Where is the output of the "routes -v" described? I guess I need to know what controller and action or other thing is triggered by a path.
